# How to separate Json fields and put them in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON and I Want to separate each field of that and then I want to use of each field separately .

I wrote below code but it does not work correctly and return undefined in alert.

here is my code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var research=
{
  "city":"1186432",
   "hotelname":"OKHTINSKAYA",
   "indate":"2017-12-23",
   "outedate":"2017-12-30",
   "rooms":[
      {
         "adultcount":"1",
         "childcount":"1,1"
      },
      {
         "adultcount":"1",
         "childcountandage":"0 "
      }
   ]
}
var re = research.rooms.adultcount
alert(re);
});
```

Comment: Here `research.rooms` is array. `adultcount` is object inside array. Access it with index

Comment: research.rooms[0].adultcount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
var re = research.rooms[0].adultcount
```

Answer (score 1):

use index to consume array property `research.rooms[0].adultcount`,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var research=  {
  "city":"1186432",
   "hotelname":"OKHTINSKAYA",
   "indate":"2017-12-23",
   "outedate":"2017-12-30",
   "rooms":[
      {
         "adultcount":"1",
         "childcount":"1,1"
      },
      {
         "adultcount":"1",
         "childcountandage":"0 "
      }
   ]
}
var re = research.rooms[0].adultcount
alert(re);
});
```

demo https://jsbin.com/zefojozevo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: jquery is missing, please check jsbin demo

Comment: That's what I wanted to say to add jquery to snippet

Comment: sorry actually I dont know how to add jquery in snippet. can you edit if you know? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`research.rooms` is an array, so to get access for each room in this array- you have to loop throw it.

For example:

```
research.rooms.map( room => alert(room.adultcount));
```

Or, in older js syntax:

```
for(var i = 0; i < research.rooms.length; i++){
    alert(research.rooms[i].adultcount);
}
```